# How to call function inside function in C++ ?

Tags: c++, singleton

**Problem:** Through C++ function I need to run  thread  function which in turn calls another  Singleton C++  function . This called function will call C function (Which runs a infinite loop to change embedded system status in every 10 millisecond).

**Question:** How would I call a function inside the function in C++? Do I need to assign instance for calling 2nd function?

Please refer the sample code and give your thoughts whether its right or wrong.
I have  a singleton class say  Singleton

```
class Singleton
{    
  private :  // constructors and values
  public :
          void runThread();
          Singleton  getInstance();
          bool ChangeStatus( int a);    
  };

 void Singleton:: runThread()
 {     
    changeStatus( 7); // is this is right way to call function inside function
 }

 bool Singleton:: changeStatus( int a);
 {
     // This calls C function which changes  the status of embedded system
 }    

 void main()
 {
     // create instance of singleton class

   Singleton *instance1 = Singleton::getInstance();

   instance1.runThread();     
   /* will this call the function  changeStatus and will this      
      changeStatus function  will change status of  embedded system 
      assuming the c function to change status is working fine.
   */
 }
```

Please ignore the basic syntax error.
When I call the `runThread` function from main will it successfully calls the changeStatus function or do I Need to specify one more instance inside **runThread** to call changeStatus something like Singleton
  `instance2 = Singleton::getInstance(); instance2->changeStatus`

Comment: Do you have a question?  If so, what is it?

Comment: Sorry Keith, I wasnt very clear . I have updated my question. Please refer to it and kindly share your thoughts

Comment: **void** getInstance(); ? instance1 **.** runThread(); ?

Comment: My question is  when i Call the runThread function from main will it successfully calls the changeStatus function ? or do i Need to specify  one more instance inside runThread to call changeStatus something like    Singleton *instance2  = Singleton::getInstance();                                    instance2->changeStatus

Comment: I think, it's best if you start with a simple `main` function that does nothing. Get that to *compile* with g++.  After that, try a program that inputs the user's name, and greets the user.

Comment: Your `getInstance` function should be static. And return a pointer (or reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function call, as written is correct.  When you're inside a member function which isn't static and you call another member function, it calls it on the same instance.  If you need to access a pointer to the instance on which the function was called, you can also use the keyword `this`.

So you could also have written `this->changeStatus(7);` and it would also work correctly.

That said, I should warn you, from reading your code, that as written right now, it isn't creating a new thread, but rather running the function inside the main thread.  If you wish to spawn an additional thread, you need code to specifically do that.  It's also not checking anything repeatedly, but these might be details you've omitted in order to simplify the question.

Comment: Hi Keith , Thanks for the reply . Well I was bit confused on using this pointer but you have cleared my doubts . Thanks for that. Also yeah , I have chalked out lot of details to simplify the things.

Answer (score 2):

In the code as written (after correcting all the obvious errors) `Singleton::runThread()`, when called on `instance1`, will indeed call `Singleton::changeStatus(int)` on the same `instance1`.